# Plotting using Matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have the following data from a text file which looks like this:

```
1       0.086800
2       0.144300
3       0.115100
4       0.127000
5       0.132000
6       0.127600
7       0.121200
8       0.142900
9       0.138000
10      0.150100
```

And I tried plotting the above data as x vs y with the following python code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plotfile('q_4_out.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), 
             names=('col1', 'col2'), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_q4.py", line 4, in <module>
    names=('col1', 'col2'), marker='o')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2422, in plotfile
    checkrows=checkrows, delimiter=delimiter, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 2937, in csv2rec
    converters = get_converters(reader, comments)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 2892, in get_converters
    func = converters[j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any way to work around this?

My text file is generated by the following code :

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define VECTOR_SIZE 65536

struct DAXPYdata
{
    /* data */
    long a;
    long X[VECTOR_SIZE];
    long Y[VECTOR_SIZE];
    long sum;
    long compute_length;
};

struct DAXPYdata daxpystr;
pthread_mutex_t mutex_sum;
int thread_id_max;


void *calcDAXPY(void *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t start_time;
    clock_t end_time;


    start_time = clock();

    double cpu_time_used;
    long vec_index;
    int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    thread_id_max = num_threads;
    /*Initialize vectors X and Y an scalar a*/

    daxpystr.a = 57;

    for(vec_index = 0 ; vec_index < VECTOR_SIZE ; vec_index++){
        daxpystr.X[vec_index] = vec_index + 1;
        daxpystr.Y[vec_index] = vec_index + 2;
    }

    if(VECTOR_SIZE % num_threads == 0)
        daxpystr.compute_length = VECTOR_SIZE/num_threads;
    else
        daxpystr.compute_length = VECTOR_SIZE/num_threads + 1;

    pthread_t call_thread[num_threads];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    int flag;
    long i;
    void *status;

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    for(i = 0 ; i < num_threads ; i++){

        flag = pthread_create(&(call_thread[i]), &attr, calcDAXPY, (void *)i);
        if(flag){

            exit(-1);
        }
    }   

    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    for(i = 0; i < num_threads ; i++) {
       flag = pthread_join(call_thread[i], &status);
       if (flag) {

          exit(-1);
          }


    }
    /* code */
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_sum);

    end_time = clock();
    cpu_time_used = (float)(end_time - start_time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cpu_time_used *= 100;
    printf("%d\t\t%lf\n", num_threads, cpu_time_used); //contents of q_4_out.txt
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *calcDAXPY(void *thread_id)
{
    int i;
    long tid;
    long vec_index;
    long start_index;
    long end_index;
    long length;
    long offset;
    long sum = 0;

    length = daxpystr.compute_length;
    offset = (long)thread_id;

    start_index = offset * length;

    if(offset == thread_id_max)
        end_index = VECTOR_SIZE - 1;
    else
        end_index = start_index + length - 1;


    for(i = start_index ; i <= end_index ; i++){
        daxpystr.X[i] += daxpystr.a*daxpystr.X[i] + daxpystr.Y[i];
    }

    pthread_exit((void *)thread_id);
}
```

My bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++))
do
    #statements
    gcc q_4_lean.c -o q_4_lean -lpthread -lm
    ./q_4_lean $i
done
```

Comment: I've tried your code and I have not had a problem. Have you copied the .txt file?

Comment: Copied as in?@eyllanesc

Comment: You've copied everything, even the line breaks.

Comment: Yes I have copied the .txt file as is

Comment: What should I change in my implementation?

Comment: The .txt file is generated by another code. I have copy pasted the contents of the .txt file here.

Comment: show another code please

Comment: The last part of main() is what generates the output/contents of my .txt file

Comment: I see the print of the data but not the code that saves the txt file. How do you save the file?

Comment: I just write a bash command ./q_4_execute.sh >> q_4_out.txt and the .txt file is generated in the current directory I work in,

Comment: show bash code please

Comment: The error I am getting is an IndexError . How do I sort it out?

Comment: So far I have had no problems.